# List all combinations of 3 equally sized partitions of a list

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

I have a vector containing 15 values and would like to find all the possible ways to partition the vector into 3 equally sized partitions. I know there is `n!/(n-r)!r!` combinations to take `r` values out of a list of `n` values with replacement & this is easily generated with `itertools` in Python.

Does there exist an easy solution to list all combinations in this case as well?

Comment: please add sample input and desired output

Comment: I actually dont know the output, but in terms of data structure, lets say a list of all combinations so with len(result)=#combinations and input you can take np.random.rand(15) , so a list of 15 random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically there will be `n!/((n/3!)^3)/3!` solutions, for example if `n=15` there will be 126126 combinations and if `n=6` there will be 15 combinations.

As the task needs to remove duplicates, which is not supported by `itertools`, I would recommend package [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import more_itertools
n = 6
assert n%3 == 0

[x for x in more_itertools.set_partitions(range(n), 3) if len(x[0]) == len(x[1]) == len(x[2])]
```

```
[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]],
 [[0, 1], [3, 4], [2, 5]],
 [[0, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3], [4, 5]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3], [4, 5]],
 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 5]],
 [[0, 2], [3, 4], [1, 5]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 4], [3, 5]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]],
 [[2, 3], [1, 4], [0, 5]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 4], [1, 5]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 5]],
 [[0, 3], [2, 4], [1, 5]],
 [[1, 3], [0, 4], [2, 5]],
 [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]]
```